# How to save ManyToMany relations in TypeOrm

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I have a products entity which looks like:

```
@Entity('products')
export class productsEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    //...Unrealted Columns
    @Column({nullable: false, unique: true})
    title: string;

    @ManyToMany( type => categoryEntity, category => category.products, {cascade: true, eager: true})
    @JoinTable({name:"products_categories",
                joinColumn: {name: 'productName', referencedColumnName: 'title'},
                inverseJoinColumn: {name: 'categoryName', referencedColumnName:'title'}
              })
    categories: categoryEntity[];

    @Column({type:"text", nullable: false})
    soldBy: userEntity;
}
```

Then i also have a categories entity:

```
@Entity('categories')
export class categoryEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({nullable: false, default: 'all', unique: true})
    title: string;
    

    @ManyToMany(()=> productsEntity, product => product.categories)
    products: productsEntity[];
}
```

Since they have a many to many relation i am not able to save anything into the junction table. Also categories are predefined and being checked in services if they exist.
I am trying this repository method:

```
  async addProduct(productDetails, username, catTitle){
        const {title, description, belongsTo, price, units}  = productDetails;
        try{ 
            let newProduct = new productsEntity();
            newProduct.title = title;
            newProduct.description = description;
            newProduct.price = price;
            newProduct.units = units;
            newProduct.categories.push(catTitle);
            newProduct.soldBy = username;
            await this.manager.save(newProduct);
        }
        catch(err){
            this.logger.error(err.message);
            throw new HttpException('Failed adding Product.', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *assume* you pushed the `catTitle` in the `newProduct.categories` as the relationships between the base on the title and the name of the product, 
That's what the *database's engine (MySQL, Postgres,...)* you're using manipulates and makes the treatments, But in **TypeOrm** we work with object,  
If you see in the relationship :

```
     @ManyToMany( type => categoryEntity, category => category.products, {cascade: true, eager: true})
    @JoinTable({name:"products_categories",
                joinColumn: {name: 'productName', referencedColumnName: 'title'},
                inverseJoinColumn: {name: 'categoryName', referencedColumnName:'title'}
              })
    categories: categoryEntity[]; // you have a list of categories not a title 

**So the solution is** to pass a category object, not just the title, to do that:

      async addProduct(productDetails, username, catTitle){
            const {title, description, belongsTo, price, units}  = productDetails;
            try{ 
        
                let newProduct = new productsEntity();
                newProduct.title = title;
                newProduct.description = description;
                newProduct.price = price;
                newProduct.units = units;
                const category= await this.CategoryRepository.findOne( { where: { title: catTitle } }); // get the category 
                  //try this approach 
  newProduct.categories = newProduct?.categories ?? []; 
  newProduct.categories.push(category);
                 // or add them from category 
    category.products= category?.products?? []; 
  category.products.push(products);
await  category.save();
                newProduct.soldBy = username;
                await this.manager.save(newProduct);
            }
            catch(err){
                this.logger.error(err.message);
                throw new HttpException('Failed adding Product.', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay understood but trying that gives me "Cannot read property push of undefined".

Comment: Anwser updated `question.categories = [category];`

Comment: @Youba   This will no longer be an array i guess. It will just change the category every time. We should see why push method is not working? Mind sharing the git repo??

Comment: @Youba here's the link https://github.com/binarydevelop/Nest-ecommerce

Comment: @TusharRoy I think you should read about arrays [Array declaration](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp), the reason I didn't use push here because the `question.categories` is not initialized, so the cleanest way is to set an array with the set of categories ( we have just one here)

Comment: @Noob did you try with the new syntax? or you want to work with push?

Comment: @Youba Yes i did whenever i add a new Product it deltes the previous relation between product and category in the junction table.

Comment: @Youba if i intialize it like newProduct.categories= []; categor.products = []; and then push it works. but same problem it keeps on deleting the relation between two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230922/discussion-between-noob-and-youba).